# Is it possible to close parent window from child (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to close parent window from child window using javascript, but its not going to work.

Please share me code if you have any.

My parent html :

```
<script>
    var winr;
    var selfw;
    function openAn(){
        selfw=self.window;
        winr=window.open("shell.htm","");

    }

    function justClose(){
        //setTimeout("closeAfterMin()",2000);

        winr.close();
    }

    function closeAfterMin(){
        alert("sd");
        selfw.close();
    }

</script>
<body onload='openAn()' >
    <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>
</body>
```

My Child html :

```
 <script>
        function closeAll(){
               window.parent.close();


        }

    </script>
    <body>
        <div onclick="closeAll();" onunload="window.opener.close();">
            Close Parent and self
        </div>
    </body>
```

Please help me..

Comment: Do you use `iframe` inside a parent window? And you want to close the parent window inside the `iframe`?

Comment: no i have not used any iframe inside a parent window

Comment: Can you include the code you're using and/or a JSFiddle?  The solutions listed already seem like they should work, yet they're not working for you.

Comment: JavaScript can only close windows that it opened. Since your parent window has most likely not been opened by JavaScript, it can't be closed by JavaScript.

Comment: @TusharAhirrao You don't use an IFRAME element?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas..check the code i posted...i have not used Iframe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [window.close() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close):

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened
>   by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console:
>   Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

You can close the child window from the parent, but not the other way around.

Comment: Yes you can. See my answer, please.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, you can disable this restriction just in your own browser. Visit `about:config`, then set `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` to `true`. Now, in your browser only, `window.close()` will work in all windows.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this

```
window.opener.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function closeW() {
   window.open('javascript:window.open("", "_self", "");
   window.close();', '_self');
}
```

call the function above with a timeout from child page. It works in IE and sometimes in Chrome too.

setTimeout(closeW, 500);

Comment: "sometimes in Chrome too" sounds too sketchy to use

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**
Having a child close a parent is bad coupling. My original answer only worked because my parent window was itself opened via javascript by a grandparent window!

The correct way to do this, to avoid uneccessary coupling, is to have the parent window poll the child, using `setInterval`, for the event that triggers the close. In this example that event is the child window closing. I actually use this to refresh part of the page with ajax rather than closing the window, but the principle is the same...

```
        $('#open_child').click( 
        function(e) {
          e.preventDefault(); 
          docs_popup = window.open($('#open_child').attr('href'),'upload_doc');

          var timer = setInterval(function() {   
              if(docs_popup.closed) {  
                  window.close();
              }  
          }, 1000); 

          return false; 
        } );
```

**Original Answer**
There is actually a fairly simple work around for this.

Create a page that does nothing but close itself, for example `close.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>window.close();</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This window should close automatically.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in the child window, redirect the opener to the page that closes itself:

```
window.opener.location.href='close.html';
```

Comment: Have you got any running example to show this working?

Comment: I have used this method on an intranet system for work.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a child-frame within a parent-frame, then use

```
window.parent.close();
```

If you mean an opened window (with window.open()), then try this

```
window.opener.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function closeAll()
{
    window.opener.justClose();
}
```

Comment: the parent window is yours ? you have control over it ?

Comment: i changed to `opener` did you notice ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a working solution (in Chrome, at least):

Here's the code for parent page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function openChild() {
    var w = window.open("parent_close_child.html", "child");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open" onclick="openChild()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for child page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function closeParent() {
    var w = window.opener;
    window.opener = self;
    w.close();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Close parent" onclick="closeParent()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Just try it!

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome.  In IE7 it prompts the user first.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome and it closes the parent window without asking anything (although, I don't know why, you have to click twice on the button). But you're right: it doesn't work in Firefox and IE.

Comment: It closes the child window.  It takes two clicks because the first time it tries to close the parent (failing because of security measures) and assigns `self` to `window.opener`.  The second time it tries to close `self` which is valid according to the MDN documentation I quoted in my answer.

Comment: OK, right. But we can tweak this code to make it work on the first click, I guess. So there is a solution in Chrome but not in other browsers.

Comment: IF this works that it's most likely a bug and you can't to expect it to work in future version.