# Close current Tab using javascript for multiple browsers(Chrome,IE,Firefox)

Tags: javascript

I have Exit button in my page, when ever i clicked on that button,current browser tab should be closed.I wrote below code this is working in IE browser only but it needs to work in Chrome and Firefox.
Please help me.

Code:
 window.top.close();

Comment: Is your page running in an `iframe`?

Comment: Yes, iframe is using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to close parent window from child (Javascript)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121755/is-it-possible-to-close-parent-window-from-child-javascript)

Comment: You can try `window.opener.close()` in your child window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in other browsers. If you check the console you will see:

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it
```